# Google colab - python - AttributeError: 'csr_matrix' object has no attribute 'row'

Tags: python, class, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to create a code that generates the matrix-vector product (sparse-matrix multiplied by vector).
But I'm getting the following error.  -

```
<ipython-input-13-b43c92e5efc9>:50: RuntimeWarning: LinearOperator subclass should implement at least one of _matvec and _matmat.
  final_add__csr = CSRMatrix(final_add)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-b43c92e5efc9> in <cell line: 89>()
     87 #final_add_data, final_add_indices, final_add_indptr, final_add_shape = p1.add(A_coo,B_coo)
     88 
---> 89 final_add_data, final_add_indices, final_add_indptr, final_add_shape = CSRMatrix.add(A_coo,B_coo)
     90 
     91 matvec1 = p1.matvec(final_add_data, final_add_indices, final_add_indptr, final_add_shape,x)

1 frames
<ipython-input-13-b43c92e5efc9> in add(other1, other2)
     48           final_add = other1 + other2
     49           #self_csr = CSRMatrix(final_add)
---> 50           final_add__csr = CSRMatrix(final_add)
     51           print("The final addition matrix in the CSR fomrat is:-")
     52           print(self_csr)

<ipython-input-13-b43c92e5efc9> in __init__(self, coo_matrix)
     10         self.shape = coo_matrix.shape
     11         self.dtype = coo_matrix.dtype
---> 12         self.row = coo_matrix.row
     13         self.col = coo_matrix.col
     14         self.data = coo_matrix.data

AttributeError: 'csr_matrix' object has no attribute 'row'
```

I am confused why I am getting this error and how to resolve this.

I have been given the following template -

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator


class CSRMatrix(LinearOperator):
    def __init__(self, coo_matrix):
        self.shape = coo_matrix.shape
        self.dtype = coo_matrix.dtype
        # You'll need to put more code here

    def __add__(self, other):
        """Add the CSR matrix other to this matrix."""
        pass

    def _matvec(self, vector):
        """Compute a matrix-vector product."""
        pass
```

with the condition that-

(1) The method **init** takes a COO matrix as input and will initialise the CSR matrix: it currently includes one line that will store the shape of the input matrix. You should add code here that extracts important data from a Scipy COO to and computes and stores the appropriate data for a CSR matrix. You may use any functionality of Python and various libraries in your code, but you should not use an library’s implementation of a CSR matrix.

(2) The method **add** will overload + and so allow you to add two of your CSR matrices together. The **add** method should avoid converting any matrices to dense matrices. You could implement this in one of two ways:
(i) you could convert both matrices to COO matrices, compute the sum, then pass this into CSRMatrix();
or
(ii) you could compute the data, indices and indptr for the sum, and use these to create a SciPy CSR matrix.

(3) The method matvec will define a matrix-vector product: Scipy will use this when you tell it to use a sparse solver on your operator.

-I am choosing the route where the code is supposed to take 2 COO matrices, add them, then convert the answer matrix to CSR and use it for further vector multiplication. I am wrting the following code-

```
import scipy
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
import numba
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
from scipy.sparse import coo_array

class CSRMatrix(LinearOperator):
    def __init__(self, coo_matrix):
        self.shape = coo_matrix.shape
        self.dtype = coo_matrix.dtype
        self.row = coo_matrix.row
        self.col = coo_matrix.col
        self.data = coo_matrix.data
        self.indices = coo_matrix.col
        self_csr = coo_matrix.tocsr()

    def add(other1, other2):
        if np.shape(other1) == np.shape(other2) :
          final_add = other1 + other2
          final_add__csr = CSRMatrix(final_add)
          print("The final addition matrix in the CSR fomrat is:-") 
          print(self_csr)
          self = self_csr
          return self.data, self.indices, self.indptr, self.shape
        else :
          print("Error : Shape of matrix A is not equal to shape of matrix B. Thus, cannot proceed towards addition to generate a final addition matrix and cannot produce matrix vector multiplication result using the final addition matrix.")


    @numba.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
    #def matvec(self.data, self.indices, self.indptr, self.shape, x):
    def csr_matvec(data, indices, indptr, shape, x):
        m, n = shape
        y = np.zeros(m, dtype=np.float64)
        for row_index in numba.prange(m):
            col_start = indptr[row_index]
            col_end = indptr[row_index + 1]
            for col_index in range(col_start, col_end):
                y[row_index] += data[col_index] * x[indices[col_index]]   
        return y

  
A = np.array([[1, 0],[3, 4],[6, 0]])   #3rows,2columns
B = np.array([[1, 2],[5, 6],[7, 8]])   #3rows,2columns
A_coo = coo_matrix(A)
B_coo = coo_matrix(B)

# Generate a random vector
rand = np.random.RandomState(0)
N = 5
x = rand.randn(2 * N)   #2rows,Ncolumns
  
final_add_data, final_add_indices, final_add_indptr, final_add_shape = CSRMatrix.add(A_coo,B_coo)

matvec1 = p1.matvec(final_add_data, final_add_indices, final_add_indptr, final_add_shape,x)
print(matvec1)
```

Comment: Adding two COO format matrices returns a CSR.  Test it your self.  Most math is mplemented in the CSR format, and and other formats are converted as needed..   It is best to test code like this piece by piece in an interactive environmrnt.

Comment: I don't know what the relevance of the 'dulicate' is, but this csr/coo error is clear.  I haven't tried to evaluate this use of class or why you need your own verson of a matvec.